# Dplyr group_by Date

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, plyr

I'm confused how dplyr group_by function handles Date objects. Here is an example where it works as expected.

```
library(data.table); library(dplyr); library(lubridate)

DT <- data.table(A = sample(1:100,12), B = (c("7-1-2015", "7-2-2015",  "7-3-2015")))
DT$B <- mdy(DT$B)
Daily_PL <- DT %>%
  group_by(B) %>%
  summarise(Avg_Value = cumsum(A))
```

When I try to use the group_by function on data I'm actually interested in it returns one value or an error. I've supplied a dropbox link with data. Thank you.

```
# Link to data
# https://www.dropbox.com/s/xo84accwtvoiw8s/Daily_Transactions.csv?dl=0
data <- read.csv("Daily_Transactions.csv", header=T)
data$Date <- mdy(data$Date)

Daily_PL <- data %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Avg_Value = cumsum(Transaction))
```

The following error is returned:

> Error: expecting a single value

Comment: I guess you need `mutate(Avg_Value=cumsum(Transaction))` because `summarise` returns only a single row per each group.  So if you have multiple rows per each 'Date', the length of `cumsum` output will be the same as the nrow of that group.  But, `summarise` can work well with `mean`, `median`, `sum` where we get a single value.

Comment: Great. Got it. Thank you